# Repeat curl command within a bash script for specific output

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I am using openphoto to upload photos from within a bash script.  Occasionally the upload fails, but all of the commands execute correctly.  The json result provides:

```
{
"message" : "oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=POST&http...,
"code" : 403,
"result" : null
}
```

The upload fails because the photo that is being uploaded is located on a remote server and occasionally fails to properly cache the file before uploading to openphoto.  It is usually only necessary to repeat the command for it to execute correctly.

My bash loop looks like this:

```
while read i; 
do ./openphoto -p -X POST -h HOSTNAME -e /photo/upload.json \
-F"photo=@$i" \
-F"tags=$(echo "$i"|cut -d'/' -f 7-|sed 's/\/[^/]*[jJ][pP][gG]//;s/\//,/g')"; 
done < files;
```

How can I get bash to repeat the command if the output contains a "code" of 403?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get bash to repeat the command if the output contains a
>   "code" of 403?

You could add a line before `done`:

```
(( $? == 403 )) && command_to_execute
```

Or if you wanted to try the command until it succeeded, you could say:

```
until (( $? == 0 )); do command_to_execute; done
```

Comment: @ftherese No.  Insert the above line before the `done` statement; after the `./openphoto ...` line.

Comment: and if command_to_execute is the exact same command... how about if I want it to just keep retrying the command until it has a result other than "code" 403?

Comment: Instead of `== 0` in the second example, say `!= 403`!

Comment: so now I have:while read i; do until (( $? == 0 )); do openphoto -p -X POST -h HOST -e /photo/upload.json -F"photo=@$i" -F"tags=$(echo "$i"|cut -d'/' -f 7- |sed 's/\/[^/]*[jJ][pP][gG]//;s/\//,/g')"; done; done < pics .... - and that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Plus, I have doubts that "403" is actually reported as an error since it comes back WITHIN the json response.

Comment: as commented earlier, add the mentioned line __after__ the _openphoto_ line.